# Low-Pass FIR that keeps all values positive

Tags: audio, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, gaussian

Let's say, that I want to low-pass the norm (hence positive values)  of an analytic signal (related to Hilbert transform). This allows me to perform experiments with the *envelope* of audio.

For low-passing, I apply a Gaussian blur. It's technically the same as applying multiple time a moving average.
The advantages of a Gaussian blur are:

- easy to implement, and enough fast.
- good attenuation in the "stop band" (I just have to iterate more moving average to improve this).
- all values remain positives. This is important, because  I use the low-passed norm to perform divisions.

But I'd like to test a low-pass with a *narrower transition band*.

Could you suggest me a *simple* solution, for a low-pass FIR (or something "linear phase" anyways) , with a **narrower transition band** than a straightforward Gaussian blur, and that allows to **keep all values positive**. For instance, with a sinc based FIR, there are oscillations around the zero line, and I want to avoid that. Adding an offset is out of question, as I want a result that is representative of the amplitude of the audio.

Comment: See [this answer to Nonnegative or positive band-limited interpolation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/40194/15347) for a restriction on the stopband attenuation of continuous-time filters with non-negative impulse responses. It won't be much different with discrete-time filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least not strictly. Low pass filters with an all positive impulse response will always have a very wide transition band.

However, if you want to do audio envelope detection both Hilbert Transform and low pass filters are the wrong tools for the job: Hilbert Transformers don't work well on broad band signals and low pass filters mess up your transients and onsets.

Comment: Thanks, you confirmed what I wanted to know:  " an all positive impulse response will always have a very wide transition band".
I don't see the problem with Hilbert Transform and broad band signal , at least when I look at the frequency response, it closely match real part. 
 Yes, low pass mess-up transients, I improved a bit results by "emulating"  a weighted gaussian Median filtering (I believe it works, tested with images).  But if I could restrict the transition band with a plain low pass, results might be better. 
I want to auto-adjust level of a "pleasing" distortion effect.